# ¿Como activar el botón de un form hijo de un formulario dinámico? Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo dos formulario, form 1 y 2. Form 1 compuesto de botones dinámicos que simulan ser mesas de restaurante y form2 que se abren cada vez que se hace click sobre el botón de una mesa en el form1.

Cada form 2 tiene un botón "ABRIR MESA" que al ser clickeado debería cambiar el color de fondo del botón de la mesa que fue abierta (en el form1). Ej: Si se clickea sobre el botón abrirMesa de la mesa 5 (ubicado en el form2), el botón de la mesa 5 en el form1 debería cambiar su fondo a verde para hacerle saber al usuario que ésta fue abierta!

Este método del form1 se activa en el form1 load y me crea un nuevo botón dinámico de mesa x:

```
     private void crearNuevaMesa()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = "btn" + i;
            btn.Height = 150;
            btn.Width = 150;

            btn.Location = new Point(200, 200);
            btn.Text = "Mesa "+i;
            btn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
            btn.Font = new Font("Georgia", 16);
            btn.Image = Properties.Resources.table;

            btn.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseMove);
            btn.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseDown);
            btn.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseUp);
            btn.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseClick);

            Controls.Add(btn);
        }
    }
```

Al hacer doble click sobre una mesa quiero que se abra un nuevo form2 ... esto no me estária andando:

```
    // NO ANDA

    private void btn_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Clicks >= 2)
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2(this);
            f.Show();

        }
    }
```

Y una vez abierto el form2, cuando haga click sobre el botón "ABRIR MESA" necesitaría que el color de fondo de esa mesa cambie a color verde; para el cual tengo este código, pero no se donde ponerlo:

```
   // FORM 1

           public void cambiarFondo(string boton)
    {
        var btn = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name == 
        boton).FirstOrDefault();
        if (btn != null)
        {
            btn.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }

   // FORM 2
   // CAMBIA EL BOTON DE LA MESA A COLOR VERDE/ABIERTA
    public void btnAbrirMesa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnAbrirMesa.BackColor = Color.Green;
        f1.cambiarFondo("btnMesa" + 1);
    }
```

A todo esto le tengo que agregar base de datos por detrás para que cuando se cierren los forms de las mesas y se vuelvan a abrir, los datos no se hallan perdido. Estoy encarando bien el problema o necesito plantear otro diseño ??
Si necesitan más código me lo piden.
Desde ya muchas gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como diría Jack el Destripador: "Vamos por partes":

> Al hacer doble click sobre una mesa quiero que se abra un nuevo form2
>   ... esto no me estária andando

Asignar doble click para un botón **no es una práctica recomendable** ya que los botones por defecto funcionan para un solo click. Si aun así quieres seguir usando este acercamiento, debes crear una clase que extienda de `Button`:

```
public class DoubleClickButton : Button
{
    public DoubleClickButton()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick | ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, true);
    }
}
```

Importa esa clase en el **Form1** y luego en el `for` del método que ya tienes `crearNuevaMesa()` metes esto:

```
private void crearNuevaMesa()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        DoubleClickButton  btn = new DoubleClickButton(); //observa como cambie a la nueva clase
        btn.Name = "btn" + i;
        btn.Height = 150;
        btn.Width = 150;

        btn.Location = new Point(200, 200);
        btn.Text = "Mesa "+i;
        btn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
        btn.Font = new Font("Georgia", 16);
        btn.Image = Properties.Resources.table;

        btn.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseMove);
        btn.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseDown);
        btn.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseUp);
        btn.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(btn_DoubleClick); // observa como añadí el nuevo evento

        Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

Tendrás que añadir la funcionalidad al doble click:

```
void btn_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
   Form2 f = new Form2(this);
   f.Show();
}
```

---

> Y una vez abierto el form2, cuando haga click sobre el botón "ABRIR
>   MESA" necesitaría que el color de fondo de esa mesa cambie a color
>   verde; para el cual tengo este código, pero no se donde ponerlo

Tal y como indicas:
`cambiarFondo()` debe ir en el **Form1** ya que es el contenedor de los botones a los que vas a cambiar el color.
`btnAbrirMesa_Click()` debe ir en el **Form2** ya que contiene el funcionamiento de un botón para este formulario.

Su funcionamiento sería:

1. El usuario pulsa en el botón `btnAbrirMesa` en el **Form2**
2. El evento indica que desde el **Form1** se debe lanzar
   `cambiarFondo()`
3. El **Form1** lo detecta y lo ejecuta cambiando el color.

Por cierto, vas a tener problemas con:

```
f1.cambiarFondo("btnMesa" + 1);
```

El motivo es que siempre te va a cambiar el color de la mesa del **btnMesa1**. Debes cambiar ese **1** por una *variable global* que tengas guardada en el **Form1**:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public string botonClickeado; //variable donde guardaremos cual es el botón clikeado
    .... 
}
```

en `btn_DoubleClick()` **guardo cual es el botón clickeado**:

```
var button = (Button)sender; //obtenemos el botón clickeado
botonClickeado = button.Name; //obtenemos su nombre btn1, btn2, etc
```

en en el **Form1** modificamos `cambiarFondo()` por:

```
public void cambiarFondo()
{
    var btn = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name == 
    botonClickeado).FirstOrDefault(); //onserva como ahora utilizamos botonClikeado, la nueva variable
    if (btn != null)
    {
        btn.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Cualquier duda por aquí estamos.

Enlaces de interés:

- [Distintas formas de pasar datos entre Forms](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms)
- [Como permitir el doble click en un botón](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486245/winforms-how-to-call-a-double-click-event-on-a-button)

Comment: Hola @Corpex ! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.Estoy intentando aplicar lo que me dices pero al crear una nueva clase y agregarla a mi App no me deja hacerla extender de Button.
Cree la nueva clase, puse Clase1 : Button ... pero el Button me lo marca en rojo y no me deja compilar ! Que estoy haciendo mal ??

Comment: El motivo del doubleClick sobre el boton es el siguiente: Como los botones son dinámicos y todos nacen en la misma posición el usuario tiene que hacer click sobre ellos para arrastrarlos y soltarlos donde él quiera. (osea, acomodar las mesas donde le gusten, así me lo pidió el profesor). El tema es que haciendo esto así, al mover las mesas también se me activa el evento del click y se me abre el form2 (lo que no quiero que pase) ... por eso se me acurrió abrir el form2 al hacer dos clicks sobre el botón y no uno solo como tenía pensado :/